# Jquery .when and deferred object not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, jquery-deferred

Im building a mobile app with backbone.js.

I need to ensure the project details are set by checking the server. The app cannot proceed until it has set the details. Im using .when() and a deferred object:

```
    console.log('before when ');

    $.when(that.setProjectDetailsWait()).done(function(data){
       console.log('after when setProjectDetailsWait and feed domain is ');
       console.log(feed_domain);
    });


    setProjectDetailsWait: function(){

        require(["app/models/project"], function (projectModel) {

                console.log('in setProjectDetailsWait');

                project = new projectModel.Project({id:project_title});

                return project.fetch({
                    api: true,
                    headers: {device_id:standard_device_id,api_key:standard_api_key},        
                    success: function (data) {

                        console.log('in setProjectDetailsWait success');

                        flickr_user_id = data.get('flickr_user_id');
                        flickr_api_key = data.get('flickr_api_key');
                        feed_domain = data.get('feed_domain');

                    },
                    error:   function(model, xhr, options){
                       console.log('in setProjectDetails error');
                    },
                });     
        });    
    },
```

However, the output is:

```
before when  router.js:237
after when setProjectDetailsWait and feed domain is  router.js:240
undefined router.js:241
now getting generic router.js:246
in setProjectDetailsWait router.js:733
in setProjectDetailsWait success
```

So the everything in .when() executes immediately and does not wait for setProjectDetailsWait() to finsih. Why is this not working??

Comment: `require()` doesn't return a promise/deferred, does it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was using require inside setProjectDetailsWait(). When I remove the require and use it at the top of the router instead, the .when() works